# How do you use the ADFS Diagnostic Tool

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

I downloaded the tool and ran it on the Windows 2008 R2 server where I have ADFS v2.0 installed.

All roles etc. are greyed out as are the buttons on the LHS.

The instructions say to select a new file e.g. adfsdiag.out in the "Data File" text box and then "run" the tool. I presume that you "run" it by clicking "Export" but it's greyed out.

I can export an adfsdiag.cab file but when I then try and select it as a data file, I get an error stating that the file does not contain valid data.

No matter what I do, the controls other than the "Data File" text box are greyed out.

I'm obviously missing something basic - just don't know what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean this [ADFS Diagnostic Tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/adfs/archive/2007/11/01/adfs-diagnostic-tool.aspx).  This tool predates AD FS 2.0, and I am pretty sure that this tool does not work with AD FS 2.0, and that there is no such diagnostic tool for AD FS 2.0.

Comment: Yup - that's the one. There are a number of posts on the web about exactly the same problem I have - everything greyed out - but no solutions. Any way to confirm that it doesn't work with ADFS v2.0?

Comment: @nzpcmad I know of no sure way to confirm, but I seem to recall a Microsoft consultant saying that since for ADFS 1.x everyone was using this ADFS Diagnostic Tool anyway, in AD FS 2.0 they (1) simplified the configuration of AD FS, and (2) built in regular health checks into AD FS itself.  The result of the health checks can be seen in the event viewer, in the 'Administration and Services Logs' -> 'AD FS 2.0' -> 'Admin' event log.  These check for things like certificate expiry.